# WordPress get_avatar() not working

Tags: wordpress, avatar

I'm trying to display the user's avatars in my pages, and I'm referring to the tutorial here: [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar). I'd like it to work like this:

```
<h2>Members</h2>
<?php echo get_avatar( 'sample@hotmail.com', 30 ); ?>
```

But nothing shows up. Here 'sample@hotmail.com' is actually in the 'Users' list of the site, and I've made sure that the 'Show Avatar' option is checked as found in the tutorial. But somehow the avatar is not showing up.

I've also tried to change the 'sample@hotmail.com' to some user ID (again, for sure it exists in the 'Users' list); still not working. I did a inspection on the code after the page is rendered, and noticed that the code is treated as comments:

```
<!--?php echo get_avatar( 'sample@hotmail.com', 30 ); ?-->
```

Can anyone give me a hint on how to resolve this?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to run PHP inside of an .html file

Answer (score 1):

Try below methods,

1.

```
<?php 

echo get_avatar( get_the_author_email(), '128', '/images/no_images.jpg', get_the_author() ); 

?>
```

2.

```
<?php 

echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('ID'), 60); 

?>
```

3.

```
<?php 

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

if ( ($current_user instanceof WP_User) ) {
    echo get_avatar( $current_user->user_email, 32 );
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The author mentions this in his original post, but just to point it out here (since I overlooked it the first time), if `get_avatar()` is returning false for you, go to Settings > Discussion and make sure Show Avatars is checked.